# ConcurrentModificationException on for loop on java.util.Set

Tags: java, spring-mvc, concurrentmodification

This is may be duplicate question but I am a bit confuse in ConcurrentModificationException. I gone through some other questions on stack Overflow also some articles related to How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException. I come to know that this exception occurs while looping on collection AND modifying the same (most common issue with `remove`).

But in my case I am just looping (`foreach`) on an `java.util.Set` then am I m getting this exception.

Moreover I am not getting this exception always, When I do load testing of my web application using `Jmeter` (150 users in 5 seconds) in this scenario I m getting exception

Here is my code where I am getting exception according to stack trace from log file

```
public static Map<String, String> getMessageMap(Locale locale) {
    Properties properties;
    Set<Object> objkeys;
    Map<String, String> messageMap = null;

    if (messageMap == null) {
        messageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // 1 Get properties file.
        properties = Utility.loadPropertiesFile(locale); // this method return properties from static veriable

        // 2 Get all keys of properties file.
        objkeys = properties.keySet();

        // 3 Add all key values into map.
        for (Object key : objkeys) { caught exception here
            String keyName = key.toString();
            if (keyName.contains("global.")) {
                messageMap.put(keyName, properties.getProperty(keyName));
            }
        }

    }
    return messageMap;
}
```

According to log file ConcurrentModificationException is occurred at line `for (Object key : objkeys)`

Here is some lines from stack trace

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.next(Unknown Source)
at com.utilities.MKCLUtility.getMessageMap(Utility.java:164)
at com.utilities.MKCLUtility.addMessage(Utility.java:49)
at com.controllers.LoginController.loginPost(LoginController.java:132)
```

What can I do to avoid this? and why this exception is occurring though I am not modifying the set.

**Updated Code**

```
Iterator<Object> iterator = objkeys.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) 
{
    String keyName = iterator.next().toString();
    if (keyName.contains("global.")) {
        messageMap.put(keyName, properties.getProperty(keyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `Set`s iterator instead

Comment: You shouldn't change the structure of a Collection within a loop, You will end up with ConcurrentModificationException. The "how to fix this?" part is already mentioned by @MadProgrammer

Comment: @TheLostMind Sorry, But I am not getting you.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I updated code in question with `iterator` is it correct?

Comment: Maybe you have indeed multiple threads calling this code or another code that modifies the properties object?

Comment: Without compiling or running it, that looks more correct

Comment: @MadProgrammer The iterator is also used in the for-each-loop variant. This does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: @Amogh - What is the relation between messageMap and properties?

Comment: Where does `messageMap` come from?

Comment: Would be explained when `properties` and `messageMap` were the same objects. Maybe show (look at) a bit more of getMessage/addMessage.

Comment: code which I updated in question still throws same exception.

Comment: @TheLostMind, `properties` (java.util.Properties) is the static variable containing property list loaded from `.properties` file and  I want to make an `messageMap` (Map<String, String>) (non-static) which contains messages from `properties` which has "global." in key part.

Comment: I updated question with full method.

Comment: `getMessageMap()` get called for every user means in my case if I load test with 250 users in 10 sec. i.e 25 users per sec. so these many times this method will execute. Is this prob.?

Comment: @Amogh - You shouldn't get this exception.. Do a deep copy of "objkeys " and try with the new objkeys Set.

Comment: @TheLostMind, Deep Copy?? You mean to say serialize the `objkeys `??

Comment: Your first code bit is extremely confusing. First off, what is the `if()` check on `messageMap` doing?  You just set it to null, now you are checking if it's null?  Second, why are you using a `Set<Object>`?  According to the APIs, `Properties` is basically a `Map<String,String>`, but you get the keys as `Objects` then do a conversion back to `String` using `toString()`? There seems to be a lot of unnecessary code going on. Also, flags went off in my head when you mentioned this method is called 25 times per second, but is a Static method.  This makes me think there is a thread safety issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the guidance from comments on question I changed by code to :

```
    public static Map<String, String> getMessageMap(Locale locale) {
    Properties properties;
    Set<Object> objkeys;


    if (messageMap == null) {
        messageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // 1 Get properties file.
        properties = MKCLUtility.loadPropertiesFile(locale);

        // 2 Get all keys of properties file.
        objkeys = properties.keySet();

        // 3 Add all key values into map.
        Iterator<Object> iterator = objkeys.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            String keyName = iterator.next().toString();
            if (keyName.contains("global.")) {
                messageMap.put(keyName, properties.getProperty(keyName));
            }
        }
    }
    return messageMap;
}
```

I made `messageMap` as static so, this function on first request will check for `null` if it is null then `messageMap` get filled then for next request it will directly return `messageMap`.

By this ConcurrentModificationException is resolved.

But still If their some suggestion you want to give then Plzz I would like to know.

Answer (score -2):

You modify the `messageMap` map while iterating over it's keyset. That's the reason you're getting the message. Just collect the matching keys inside a `ArrayList` object, then iterate over that and modify the `messageMap` map .

EDIT :

the exception is actually referring to the `messageMap` and not `properties` . Are these 2 related in any way (common keys) . Is the code not shown here iterating over `messageMap` too ?

Comment: But I don't think I am modifying `properties` map. At which line I am modifying it. As you said I am taking all its key set in another `set` and iterating on it `objkeys=properties.keySet();`

Comment: Clarification about messageMap and not properties is added in comment to question and I am not iterating over messageMap I am just returning it.

Comment: Does the new code using an iterator also throw the CME ?